# Use method from super super class?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm using [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley) to make HTTP requests. In particular I want to make a request that returns a JSON object as the response. So I'm using

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null,
        response -> {},
        error -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error fetching config", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("action", "get_config");
        params.put("token", getToken());
        return params;
    }
};
```

The class hierarchy is `JsonObjectRequest extends JsonRequest extends Request`.

In `Request` there is an implementation of `getBody()` that calls `getParams()` and builds a POST body from it.

Unfortunately `JsonRequest` overrides this implementation and replaces it with one that simply returns `null` (the "body" I'm passing in).

I could now override `getBody()` myself, but with what? Is there a way to call the implementation in `Request` without actually copying over the code *and all the private methods it uses*?

Comment: How about `Request.super.getBody()`

Comment: @Rogue `'com.android.volley.Request' is not an enclosing class`

Comment: @user15244370 I saw that one and the top answer is asking *why*, so I thought I'll write a new question with focus on the *why*.

Comment: @AndreKR my mistake, that line was for if you had an object extending `Request`. Though you could make such an object which specifically just skip's `JsonRequest`'s functionality in that way